How to set permanent 'always on visible workspace' xfce4's applications windows?
I try to figure out the way to make it permanent:

I know that's the firefox default behavior. I have no clue how it's implemented.
How to do it?

This is how I manage this:
You can use this wrapper, by example ~/bin/signal-desktop:
#!/bin/bash

/bin/signal-desktop "$@" &
sleep 3
wmctrl -r signal -b add,sticky

For sure, you need to install wmctrl if needed.
Make sure you place the script earlier than other paths in PATH variables, Ex in ~/.bashrc:
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH

